# Re-installed Chrome returns Bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome

I have reinstalled Chrome and all the bookmarks are there again - why?  I deleted the app and downloaded it again.  Where are the bookmarks kept - on the operating system?

Comment: What operating system? A quick Google search comes up with many results for all the major OSs, many of which are already asked in SuperUser

Answer (score 1):

From the Chrome menu **⋮** browse to *Settings* -> under the **Sign in** heading click the *Advanced sync settings...* button and under *Choose what to sync* check if there is a check mark to the left of *Bookmarks*. If you have *Bookmarks* checked, Google will sync your Chrome bookmarks across multiple operating systems and devices. To disable this option, uncheck *Bookmarks*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the bookmarks are kept in the Application Data folder. To access the folder with the bookmarks, navigate to the following directories:

**Windows XP**

C:\Documents and Settings\ *YOUR USER NAME* \Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks

**Windows Vista/7/8/10**

C:\Users\ *YOUR USER NAME* \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

**OSX**

(Main HD)/Users/ *YOUR USER NAME* /Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default

**Linux**

/home/ *YOUR USER NAME* /.config/google-chrome/Default/

or

/home/ *YOUR USER NAME* /.config/chromium/Default/

***I hope this helps!***